# Что лежит внутри файла-таблицы БД mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Вопрос по mysql. Решил посмотреть, что лежит в таблице базы данных.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| qwe                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.24 sec)

mysql> USE qwe;
Database changed

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
Empty set (0.11 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE table1(name VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL, sourname VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.92 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+---------------+
| Tables_in_qwe |
+---------------+
| table1        |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table1 (name, sourname) VALUES ('Vasia', 'Vasiliev');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+-------+----------+
| name  | sourname |
+-------+----------+
| Vasia | Vasiliev |
+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

У меня есть папка-БД `qwe` , в которой только 1 таблица есть - `table1`.
То есть, я создал таблицу `table1`, в нее запихал два поля - `name`   и `sourname`, запись добавил с `"Vasia" "Vasiliev"`, открыл эту таблицу в хекс-редакторе, но не увидел там `"Vasia" "Vasiliev"`, а увидел это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос - **ГДЕ лежит запись с ячейками `"Vasia" "Vasiliev"`?****Что это за файл db.opt (внутри него указана кодировка и коллэйшн) лежит в папке-БД qwe?**

Comment: Какой движок таблиц по умолчанию в вашей БД ? Если innoDB, то данные лежат в общем файле данных innoDB. Если MyISAM то файлов должно быть несколько. .frm - описание структуры Вообще в официальной документации MySQL можно найти описания хранения данных

Comment: наверно, innoDB, потому что, если открыть хэкс-редактором таблицу, то встречаются символы innoDB

Comment: Для innoDB по умолчанию все лежит в одном файле ibdata1 на корне каталога с данными. В папках баз только описания структуры